# How can I make sure that my tensorFlow Java program is using my GPU on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, tensorflow, gpu, inference

So I had an implementation of Java tensorFlow for CPU in Windows. Now that versions after tf 1.10 allow GPU computing in windows I tried to make the connection. 
Now in the maven pom I call tensorflow_jni_gpu instead of tensorflow_jni. the program does not fail, but there does not seem to be any difference in computation. How can I check if my program is using the GPU or how can I force it to use it?

Answer (score 2):

To use GPU, you should have the following dependencies in POM take care of the libtensorflow and not tensorflow:
`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>libtensorflow</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>libtensorflow_jni_gpu</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>proto</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

`

And following code:

```
byte[] config = ConfigProto.newBuilder()
            .setGpuOptions(GPUOptions.newBuilder().setAllowGrowth(true))
            .build().toByteArray();       
    final Runner runner = Session.runner();
    runner.setOptions(config);
```

Regarding to know if it is running on CPU or GPU, you should see it in app log either tensorflow has not been build regarding certain CPU instruction or tensorflow manage to load CUDA dll or so regaring OS

Comment: So the only way to know if the GPU assignation has been correct is via the log? Is not possible to retrieve the GPU in use with commands?